# Message error 'C:/Program' not found with Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm running a 64-bit Windows 7 platform.

I have added to my installed programs/libraries:

- Rtools
- R (software)
- Rcpp (R package)
- inline (R package)

I tried out a snippet found [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/rcpp_workshop_introduction_user2012.pdf)

```
## now with Rcpp and C++
library(inline)
# and deﬁne our version in C++
src <- "int n = as<int>(ns);
double x = as<double>(xs);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) x=1/(1+x);
return wrap(x); "
l <- cxxfunction(signature(ns="integer", xs="numeric"),
body=src, plugin="Rcpp")
```

But that doesn't work (That is not a surprise to be honest as I even didn't specified eg the location of Rtools). I get the following error message:

```
Error in system(cmd, intern = !verbose) : 'C:/Program' not found
```

I'm not sure of what that means. And, I have been stuck there for a couple of hours now. Can anyone help me a bit, please?

Comment: It is almost certainly a problem in quoting a path with a space in it. Can you try running `cxxfunction(signature(ns="integer", xs="numeric"),body=src, plugin="Rcpp",verbose=TRUE)` by setting `verbose` to `TRUE` it will display the command it is trying to run.

Comment: @nograpes I'm pretty sure that bug is fixed in recent versions of r.

Comment: @edouard That command was intended to identify, not fix the problem. Rather than displaying it as an answer, it makes more sense to include the output as an update to your question. Also, given that the error shows that it could not write the error file, I suspect that R does not have permission to write to the `C:/Program Files/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/R` directory. Try running R 'as Administrator', or alternatively, try installing R to `C:/R-3.0.1`. This will allow the error file to be written, and hopefully the problem can be identified.

Comment: @hadley I wasn't aware that there was ever a bug. I was just guessing based on `'C:/Program' not found.`

Comment: Sorry, for the mess. I installed R at the root in C:/ but I get a similar message error. I feel lost!

Comment: @edouard It would still really help if you copied the stuff that you put into your answer into the question. Also, it would help if you posted the exact error message you are getting now.

Comment: @edouard: Sorry about the troubles but lots of people use this happily.  I would suggest to uninstall (again!!), make sure that the registry has not remnants, install R, and try again. Also try RStudio which has some added checks which may make the difference.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for your reply. I reinstalled R in a folder with no space in the name. Running the same snippet as above, I now get: Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file16283f102317.cpp 2> file16283f102317.cpp.err.txt' had status 1

Comment: Start R. Execute: `library(Rcpp); evalCpp("2 * M_PI");`. If you see twice pi, you have a working setup. If not, revisit your setup.  It works for thousands of other users.  And we do have a mailing list...

Comment: oups ...   Error in sprintf("SEXP get_value(){ return wrap( %s ) ; }", code) : 
  object 'M_PI' not found

Comment: I think R doesn't find Rtools. How do I indicate to R where does Rtools locate?

Answer (score 3):

The [R on Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f) says in Question 2.2:

> If you want to be able to build packages from sources, we recommend
>   that you choose an installation path not containing spaces.

Also see Question 2.16 of that FAQ.  I am fairly certain that we also make that point repeatedly in the Rcpp documentation.

Now, if you forgo the inline package, and try working in RStudio, then you might get around this (as there are more efforts to protect the `$PATH` with spaces).

But in short, I would reinstall R into, say `C:\R\R-$version` as it is the only way to get default behaviour on all examples. And we have lots of them.  It's worth reinstalling.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that this was recommended. Perhaps off-topic, but do you have any idea why the installer uses `C:\Program Files` as the default install location? Wouldn't it make sense to have it install directly to `C:\R\R-$version`?

Comment: That conflict between the R-on-Windows FAQ and the installer has been bugging me for years too.  Note the 'if develop' conditional in the FAQ -- maybe Windows is seen (correctly?) as a 'run code mostly, write code rarely' environment.  But I would have changed the installer _years_ ago.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this spaces in the path bug is now fixed, but I don't recall what version of R it made it in to.

Comment: @hadley I still think you are mistaken.  If you call `R CMD INSTALL` without a lot of extra path sanitizing (as Rcpp and inline may do) you get the error.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel oops, yeah, I was thinking of https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15422. As usual with BDR, I think that did lead to a fix - https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/687a521946fea2887acdb438eea9220e9248c432

Comment: @hadley Thanks, liked your comment here -- I did try to sanitize with `shQuote()` as well but not to complete satisfaction. Best bet is to avoid spaces in PATH ...

Answer (score 0):

Following nograpes suggestion I get:

```
>> setting environment variables: 
PKG_LIBS =  C:/Users/ (...) /DOCUME~1/R/WIN-LI~1/3.0/Rcpp/lib/x64/libRcpp.a

>> LinkingTo : Rcpp
CLINK_CPPFLAGS =  -I"C:/Users/  (...)  /Documents/R/win-library/3.0/Rcpp/include" 

>> Program source:

1 : 
2 : // includes from the plugin
3 : 
4 : #include <Rcpp.h>
5 : 
6 : 
7 : #ifndef BEGIN_RCPP
8 : #define BEGIN_RCPP
9 : #endif
10 : 
11 : #ifndef END_RCPP
12 : #define END_RCPP
13 : #endif
14 : 
15 : using namespace Rcpp;
16 : 
17 : 
18 : // user includes
19 : 
20 : 
21 : // declarations
22 : extern "C" {
23 : SEXP file47844fc6c7a( SEXP ns, SEXP xs) ;
24 : }
25 : 
26 : // definition
27 : 
28 : SEXP file47844fc6c7a( SEXP ns, SEXP xs ){
29 : BEGIN_RCPP
30 : int n = as<int>(ns);
31 : double x = as<double>(xs);
32 : for (int i=0; i<n; i++) x=1/(1+x);
33 : return wrap(x); 
34 : END_RCPP
35 : }
36 : 
37 : 

Compilation argument:
 C:/Program Files/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file47844fc6c7a.cpp 2>         file47844fc6c7a.cpp.err.txt 
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'file47844fc6c7a.cpp.err.txt': No such file or directory
```

But, I admit that doesn't help me that much.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error on windows when running this

```
system("C:/Program Files/...", intern=TRUE)
```

it was because there's a space in the path (i.e. in `Program Files`).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67912610/5783745) is what solved for me.

Instead of `system()`, use `system2()`.

```
system2("C:/Program Files/...")
```

And that will work.