# Message error 'C:/Program' not found with glmmadmb() in R

Tags: r, emacs

Using:

- Windows 7
- Emacs 24.3
- ESS
- R 3.1.1

The error from a `glmmadmb()` call:

`Error in system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  :   'C:/Program' not found"`

Prompted me to reinstall R in a pathname that had no spaces, as recommended from this post concerning the [same error (with `Rcpp`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944594/message-error-c-program-not-found-with-rcpp).  I did such, and the error persisted.

The code ran without error in Rstudio with the standard/default R installation (pathname with spaces).  My problem occurred with EMACS/ESS/R 3.1.1 when trying to fit a `glmmadmb()`, which prompted me to run with `debug=TRUE`

```
>   gaFP0<-glmmadmb(count~tx,
                    random=~(1|Feed)+(1 | Pint),
                    data=dnoNM,family="nbinom",zeroInflation=TRUE,
                    debug=TRUE)
```

Which output:

```
platform: windows 64 
executable name: glmmadmb.exe 
bin_loc: C:/RLIB/glmmADMB/bin/windows64/glmmadmb.exe 
using temp directory
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq2AddG\glmmADMB90e434c55ff2 
creating temp directory changed working directory to
C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpq2AddG/glmmADMB90e434c55ff2 
Command line: "C:/RLIB/glmmADMB/bin/windows64/glmmadmb.exe" -maxfn 500 -maxph 5 -noinit -shess 
Error in system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  : 
'C:/Program' not found
 changed working directory to h:/
removed temp directory
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq2AddG\glmmADMB90e434c55ff2
```

As a note -- I also reinstalled Emacs to have no spaces in the pathname and still had the error, although I did not uninstall the original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hack I employed so that EMACS/ESS could run the code was the following `Sys.setenv()` statement before the function call.

```
>   Sys.setenv(R_SHELL = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe")
>   gaFP0<-glmmadmb(count~tx,
                    random=~(1|Feed)+(1 | Pint),
                    data=dnoNM,family="nbinom",zeroInflation=TRUE,
                    debug=TRUE)
```

Now `glmmadmb()` runs as expected.  See the reasons as explained by [Ross Boylan](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2013q1/020114.html) (this Q&A stackoverflow post was written with his permission).