# Install two versions of rtools

Tags: r, rtools

I have `R version 4.0.2` and `Rtools40` installed in windows on the local disk `C:\`. I recently installed `Microsoft R Client version 3.5.2`, in the local disk `E:\`. My question is how can I install `Rtools35.exe` on the `E:\` disk without interfering with the `Rtools40` variable environment?. In other words, I want to have both versions of rtools and that they work without problems, Thanks.

When switching to R 3.5.2, rtools does not work.

```
library(Rcpp);
evalCpp("2 * M_PI")
Error in system(cmd, intern = !showOutput) : 'E:/Program' not found
Error in system(cmd, ignore.stderr = TRUE, intern = TRUE) : 
  'E:/Program' not found
```

R 4.0.2 works

```
library(Rcpp);
evalCpp("2 * M_PI")
6.283185
```

Comment: How about using .Rprofile  file - Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Rtools/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";")

Comment: The problem is that I install Rtools on `E:/` disk , and it doesn't seem to find the path.

Comment: Even if you explicitly set it in the .Rprofile file? In the .Rprofile file you have to write Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("E:/Rtools/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";")   -- of course with the path where you installed RTools

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539125/how-to-add-rtools-bin-to-the-system-path-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that `Microsoft R Client version 3.5.2`, was installed in a path with space `E:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client`, it was solved by installing it in a path without spaces `E:\Microsoft\R-Client`, such as suggested in: [Message error 'C:/Program' not found with Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944594/message-error-c-program-not-found-with-rcpp)

Answer (score 0):

Read the instructions at [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)  It should not be too hard to set up your two installation of R  (4.0 and 3.6.X) so that each one queries a different `.Renviron` file and thus sets up a different path to the desired `Rtools` repository.