# install multiple versions of rtools in one machine

Tags: r, rtools

Is there any way we can install multiple versions of R and Rtools in one machine and the tell you script to use particular version according to your need.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680272/install-two-versions-of-rtools

Comment: Or this: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-windows/2016q4/000055.html