# in R, invoke external program in path with spaces with command line parameters

Tags: r, command-line-arguments, path-separator

A combination of frustrating problems here.
Essentially I want R to open an external program with command line parameters. I am currently trying to achieve it on a Windows machine, ideally it would work cross-platform.

The program (chimera.exe) is in a directory containing spaces: `C:\Program Files\Chimera1.15\bin\`
The command line options could be for instance a `--nogui` flag and a script name, so from the shell I would write (space-specifics aside):

```
C:\Program Files\Chimera1.15\bin\chimera.exe --nogui scriptfile
```

This works if I go in windows cmd.exe to the directory itself and just type `chimera.exe --nogui scriptfile`

Now in R:

I've been playing with `shell()`, `shell.exec()`, and `system()`, but essentially I fail because of the spaces and/or the path separators.

most of the times system() just prints "127" for whatever reason:

```
> system("C:/Program Files/Chimera1.15/bin/chimera.exe")
[1] 127`
```

back/forward slashes complicate the matter further but don't make it work:

```
> system("C:\Program Files\Chimera1.15\bin\chimera.exe")
Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "C\P"

> system("C:\\Program Files\\Chimera1.15\\bin\\chimera.exe")
[1] 127

> system("C:\\Program\ Files\\Chimera1.15\\bin\\chimera.exe")
[1] 127

> system("C:\\Program\\ Files\\Chimera1.15\\bin\\chimera.exe")
[1] 127
```

When I install the program in a directory without spaces, it works. How can I escape or pass on the space in `system()` or related commands or how do I invoke the program otherwise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `system2` as it does not use the `cmd` line processor and use `r"{...}"` to avoid having to double backslashes.  This assumes R 4.0 or later.  See `?Quotes` for the full definition of the quotes syntax.

```
chimera <- r"{C:\Program Files\Chimera1.15\bin\chimera.exe}"
system2(chimera, c("--nogui",  "myscript"))
```

For example, this works for me (you might need to change the path):

```
R <- r"{C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1\bin\x64\Rgui.exe}"  # modify as needed
system2(R, c("abc", "def"))
```

and when Rgui is launched we can verify that the arguments were passed by running this in the new instance of R:

```
commandArgs()
## [1] "C:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-4.1\\bin\\x64\\Rgui.exe"
## [2] "abc"                                       
## [3] "def"
```

### system

Alternately use `system` but put quotes around the path so that `cmd` interprets it correctly -- if it were typed into the Windows `cmd` line the quotes would be needed too.

```
system(r"{"C:\Program Files\Chimera1.15\bin\chimera.exe" --nogui myscript}")
```

Comment: I will try this later; many thanks already. Can you point me to a reference for th r"{}" synthax, haven't seen that before? Any thoughts on why the `system()` double backslash space escape fails or we be like \*shrug\* with this command?

Comment: Have added responses to the answer.

Comment: `?Quotes` revealed a lot of information that are extremely useful but easily overlooked during earlier days of learning R. Thanks.

Comment: Very helpful. Your solution solved for me. I referenced it on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75776911/5783745).